# Combining AppDbContext And IdentityDbContext Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am Using EF 6.0 and want to combine `AppDbContext` & `IdentityDbContext` into a single context which is `AppDbContext`.

This is a requirement as i have other tables which has relations with the AspNetUsers table created by EF.

The problem is EF is creating two tables for Users such as `AspNetUsers` and `IdentityUsers`.

Also If i use `DbSet<ApplicationUser>` in DbContext instead of `DbSet<IdentityUsers>` , Then add-migration throws up error.

My AppDbContext is

```
    public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>,IDisposable
    {
        public AppDbContext()
            : base("MvcArchBSEFDB", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static AppDbContext Create()
        {
            return new AppDbContext();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }

        //public DbSet<ApplicationUser> AppUsers { get; set; } // breaks migration
//Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'AppUsers ' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'MvcArchBS.DAL.Setp.ApplicationUser'.

        public DbSet<IdentityUser> AppUsers { get; set; } // Creates Two Tables AspNetUsers & IdentityUser

        public DbSet<IdentityUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IdentityUserClaim> Claims { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IdentityUserLogin> Logins { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Module> Modules { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubModule> SubModules { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PageMst> Pages { get; set; }



        public void Dispose()
        {
            base.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

And My ApplicationUser Class is

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        status = "A";
        reptngusrid = "admin";
    }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
    public int usrid { get; set; }
    public string usrdescr { get; set; }
    public int empid { get; set; }
    public int usrgrpid { get; set; }
    [StringLength(1)]
    public string status { get; set; }

    public string reptngusrid { get; set; }
    public int defmodid { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string cltur { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("defmodid")]
    public virtual Module Module { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

How do i get this to work ? I want to use something like context.AppUsers in my queries which i am unable to get.

Comment: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> already has DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }. Same for all other Identity entities. You should not include them.

Comment: @tmg yes. but it does not show up in AppDbContext property

Comment: @Deb It should be there as `Users`, not `AppUsers`.  As per @tmg above, you also should remove `UserRoles`, `Claims` and `Logins` - they are all already defined in `IdentityDbContext`.

Comment: @BrendanGreen My context object does not show any of the members of IdentityDbContext. That is why i added them.But still Users does not show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my Service Layer Project also needs a reference to `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll`.

Once i added that all identity entity sets are available now with my context.

Also as **tmg** & **Brendan** had pointed out the `IdentityDbContext` members `DbSets` are not required in the `AppDbContext`.

Hope this helps someone.